# Is it possible to open a new space with the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces

There is a keyboard shortcut to open up spaces <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> and you can press <kbd>alt</kbd> to see the new space +.  Is there anyway to create a new space with a keyboard command?

Answer (score 1):

There are only three ways to create a new space in OS X Lion and above:

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to launch Mission Control hover the Pointer over the top left or right corner, where a window will now appear with a + sign – by clicking the + a new space is generated
   [image]
2. drag and drop an application window from Mission Control to the top right or left corner of your screen; the Desktop icon will appear, and a new space is gererated and your window's application is assigned to it.
3. Once enabling an application's full screen mode by clicking the right-hand corner of an application window's title bar, a new space is generated for the application

---

> #### Set Mission Control shortcuts
>
> - 1) Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Mission Control.
> - 2) In the Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts section, open the pop-up menus to choose keyboard shortcuts, mouse shortcuts, or both. If you have a multiple-button mouse, you see two columns of pop-up menus in this section.
> - 3) Click Hot Corners, then open any of the pop-up menus and choose actions to perform when you move the pointer to a screen corner.
>     After you set an active corner, move your mouse to that corner of the screen to see the result.

---

[source1](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3670)   —   [source2](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10565)   —   [source3](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14298)

Comment: I am aware of all of these options. The question is asking how to do this with a keyboard shortcut.